# Are there hypersurfaces with connected complement in a Banach space?

Tags: differential-topology, banach-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is well-known that a smooth hypersurface $M$ (closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is the zero locus of a global smooth function (whose gradient is nonzero on $M$); from this one easily deduces that
its complement has exactly two connected components.

Now let $X$ be a Banach spaces and let us say that $M\subset X$ is a **closed
hypersurface** if

- $M$ is a closed, connected subset of $X$
- for each $x_0\in M$
  we can find an open neighbourhood $V$ and a function $F\in C^1(V,\mathbb{R})$ s.t.
  $M\cap V=F^{-1}(0)$ and $DF(x_0)\in E^*\setminus\{0\}$.

It is still easy to show that $X\setminus M$ has at most two connected components. Are there examples of hypersurfaces with connected complement?

I suspect that if $X$ is a Hilbert space one could try to construct a global function again via line bundles, but the lack of compactness could be a problem..

Comment: The Klein bottle embeds in 4-space, and I am tempted to post this as an answer, showing that the complement may be connected. I just don't feel I quite understand what is going on, so will try to convince myself a bit more first.

Comment: Yes but in the 4-space it hasn't codimension 1